# BB10 simulator : "This file could not be found"

Tags: blackberry-simulator, blackberry-10

Im studying with BB10 simulator. Today I follow an example here :

http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/package_and_launch_your_app_bb10.html

The problem is when I package and build in Ripple Emulator, the app in BB10 simulator cant run :

[image]

Can someone tell me why and how to fix this problem? Tks so much :)

Comment: Did you package it correctly for simulator (x86)? If you package it for Device, the compiled executable is for the ARM platform, which can not launch on simulator (and will fail to find the right file).

Comment: In the target field there is only Simulator and Device, no Simulator (x86). In the above picture I chose Simulator

Answer (score 0):

The problem is so simple, it must be index.html instead of index.htm